# Why is my 2nd mouse button not detecting unity (beginner)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a multiplayer fps game using photon and the ads is a big part. For some reason, the right mouse button is not registering, but every other one is. It works on my mouse outside of unity, but it does not work inside. My lmb is working for the ads, so I do not know why this is the case.
Here is the snippet for the aim;

```
 }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
            {
                animator.SetBool("rmb", true);
            }
            else
            {
                animator.SetBool("rmb", false);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetMouseButton(2)` is for the middle-click button (pushing down on the scroll wheel), not the right mouse button. Use `GetMouseButton(1)` instead:

*Small tip, you can skip the if check entirely just by passing the result of Input.GetMouseButton directly to the "rmb" parameter of the animator:*

```cs
animator.SetBool("rmb", Input.GetMouseButton(1));
```

Documentation: [Scripting API: Input.GetMouseButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html)

Comment: Hi, @ipodtouch0218, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the broader community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @DylanSantwani ^ (wrong ping)

Comment: @ipodtouch0218 oh right